# Javascript: Replace specific words in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I like to change URL in function of the language so for that I tried this code:

```
var dec = {
  "agence": "agency",
  "conseil": "consulting",
  "partnaires": "partners",
  "a-propos": "about",
  "recherche": "search"
}
var url = window.location.href;
var urlRedirect = url.replace("/fr/", "/en/");
urlRedirect = urlRedirect.replace(!!) // how can I use the dec ?
```

For example if my URL like this:**http://exemple.com/fr/agence**

It should be like this:**http://exemple.com/en/agency**

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: what he's doing is whatever matches the key in dec should be replaced with the value, in his example "agence" -> "agency"

Comment: @ChrisLi `agence`->`agency`, `conseil`->`consulting`, etc of object `dec`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over the keys of the object using the `for...in` loop, then check if the key string is present in the `URL`, if yes, then `replace()` it with the value of that key.

See below, where I'm using a fake URL just for this example:

```js
var dec = {
  "agence": "agency",
  "conseil": "consulting",
  "partnaires": "partners",
  "a-propos": "about",
  "recherche": "search",
  "fr":"en"
}

//var url =  window.location.href;
//let's fake a url here:
var url = "http://exemple.com/fr/agence";
console.log("entry URL: ", url)

for (var key in dec){
  if (url.indexOf(key) > -1){
    url = url.replace(key, dec[key])
  }
}

console.log("output URL: ", url);
```

**Note:** This will work, but if the URL has one of the words from `dec` in the main part of the URL, it will also change (for example: `www.agence.com/fr` will become `www.agency.com/en`) So, if you want just the path, the part after the `/` to change, use `window.location.pathname`, then replace just that part.

Answer (score 3):

You have to get the string after the last slash and replace it by whatever `dec[string]` is:

```js
var dec = {
  "agence": "agency",
  "conseil": "consulting",
  "partnaires": "partners",
  "a-propos": "about",
  "recherche": "search"
}
var url = "http://exemple.com/fr/agence"
var urlRedirect = url.replace("/fr/", "/en/");
var positionOfLastSlash = urlRedirect.lastIndexOf('/');
var lastPart = urlRedirect.substring(positionOfLastSlash + 1);
var firstPart = urlRedirect.substring(0, positionOfLastSlash+1);

if (lastPart in dec) {
  console.log(firstPart+dec[lastPart]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build a regex using `Object.keys` joining each key with `|` (or in a regex) then you could use it in the replace callback calling the value of `dec`.

```js
var dec = {
  agence: "agency",
  conseil: "consulting",
  partnaires: "partners",
  "a-propos": "about",
  recherche: "search"
};
var url = "http://exemple.com/fr/agence/conseil/partnaires/a-propos/recherche";
var urlRedirect = url.replace("/fr/", "/en/");

var r = new RegExp(Object.keys(dec).join("|"), "gi");

urlRedirect = urlRedirect.replace(r, m =>dec[m]);

console.log(urlRedirect);
```